# Playback a MP3 blob in a cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, mp3, html5-audio

In my webapp, users can record their voice, then play it back to hear the result.

It's a nodejs (meteor) app, and the record is done with Mp3LameEncoder objects, which allow me to get a MP3 blob. Once I got it, I use windowURL to get the blob url. I then add that url as a src attribute to my audio html5 element. On desktop / mobile browsers, that works great (on most of the browsers).

```
input.disconnect();
  processor.disconnect();

  if ( encodingProcess === 'direct' ) {
    if ( finish ) {
      blob = encoder.finish();
      console.log("Stopping and saving", blob);
      t.$('#playback').attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      //saveRecording(blob);
    } else {
      encoder.cancel();
    }
  } else {
    worker.postMessage({ command: finish ? 'finish' : 'cancel' });
  }
```

But in my cordova app, nothing to do : whatever I tried, I was always unable to playback the audio. The src attr is correctly set, but when I use the native control's play button, nothing happens. But the blob is well there, and it can be uploaded to the storage server, and heard correctly after.

Also, in my cordova app, I'm able to listen to audio with `<audio>` when the source is from a remote server (wether it is my AWS bucket or a static file on my app server).

I decided to try to use the media cordova plugin to record and playback the sound, and then transparently upload the recorded blob, but I can't use the mic for both the `Media()` and the JS lib at the same time.

Since I have that blob somewhere in my memory (I can upload it, even with the cordova app), how could I make it playable BEFORE being uploaded ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some platforms HTML5 media elements can't play the blobs that don't have metadata, that is, the ones that weren't created by FileReader or XHR. If that's the reason, one solution might be to fake download (XHR) the blob as blob, then using the URL for the new one:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("get", yourBlobURL);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function () {
   var yourNewBlob = xhr.response;
   audioElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(yourNewBlob)
};
xhr.send();
```

If your recordings are short, you can also consider using data-URLs instead of blobs.

And if all you want is to get it heard, you can switch to [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) as well.